# CMake wrapper for new command-line tools

Tags: cmake, plantuml

I'm trying to provide a simple CMake function to render [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) diagrams to PNG as part of my build process.  The idea is that I have a bunch of `.uml` files containing PlantUML diagrams that I want to render to PNG as part of my build process.  I would like to have a function similar to `add_library()` *et. al.* that renders any diagram for which the image file is older than the source file.

Using [`add_custom_command()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command), I came up with the following snippet:

```
#
# Create top-level target that renders a PlantUML diagram to a PNG image.
#
function(add_diagram target source)

  # Program used to render the diagram.
  set(plantuml java -jar ${PLANTUML_JARFILE})

  # Diagram source file basename used to create output file name.
  get_filename_component(output ${source} NAME_WE)

  # Render the diagram and write an "${output}.png"
  # file in the current binary folder.
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${output}.png
    COMMAND
      ${plantuml} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -tpng ${source}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY
      ${source}
    COMMENT
      "Rendering diagram '${output}'."
  )

  # Top-level target to build the output file.
  add_custom_target(${target}
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${output}.png)

endfunction()
```

And I invoke this function as:

```
add_diagram(foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.uml)
```

where `foo.uml` is a file containing a PlantUML diagram.  At a very basic level, this "works" in that it creates a named top-level target that I can build manually (e.g. using `make foo`, `nmake foo`, `jom foo`, etc.).

How can I add this target to the default target (all?) such that this is automatically built with the rest of the libraries and executables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [CMake documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_target):

> **add_custom_target**: Add a target with no output so it will always be built.
>
> If the **ALL** option is specified it indicates that this target should be added to the default build target so that it will be run every time.
>
> Dependencies listed with the **DEPENDS** argument may reference files and outputs of custom commands created with add_custom_command() in the same directory (CMakeLists.txt file).

If you are using Visual Studio, the only drawback is that it will create a new project for each target.

Comment: Nice find!  I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was to add `ALL` in the `add_custom_target()` call and everything works like a charm!

Comment: What are you doing if the OS you are running the build does not have installed plantuml?